# Monitor changes done by small program

Tags: linux, terminal

I need to install small programs I do not fully trust.

Therefore I would like to monitor all files for changes - whether this script places some files it is not supposed to or edits others.
As I want to monitor all folders and files I thought about using something similar to rsync - but is there an alternative to only watch for changes?

Does this way guarantee that I catch everything the software changes? Or are there some kind of "registry-entries" / changes in the configuration, I could miss?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use some kind of sandbox (probably the most straightforward way nowadays is to use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)).

You could use Git to track all the changes that are made into the sandbox/container:

- Initialize a git repo in the root dir
- Add all files and commit as the base version
- Execute the install script you do not trust
- Using `git status` is going to show you all the changes that were made during installation.